# Which animal survived outside of Noachs teiva

Tags: parashat-noach

Which animal survived outside the teiva? 
I know og melech havashan survives but which animal?

Comment: Why do you assume there is such an animal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a riddle

Comment: The Dove survived outside the ark, at least towards the end of the flood

Comment: The fish survived in the water around the teivah. Would that count?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya.

No **animals** survived as it says [7 (21)](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8170#showrashi=true):

> And all flesh perished that moved upon the earth, among the fowl, and
>   among the cattle, and among the beasts, and among all creeping
>   creatures that creep upon the earth and all mankind.

But the fish survived as can be seen in [Zevachim 113b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%92_%D7%91)

> דאמר רב חסדא בדור המבול לא נגזרה גזרה על דגים שבים, שנאמר מכל אשר
>   בחרבה מתו, ולא דגים שבים.
>
> Rav Chisda said “in the generation of the flood, there was no decreee
>   against the fish in the sea  as it says, “all that was on the dry land
>   died” [Braishis 7 (22)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%96_%D7%9B%D7%91)
>   and not the fish in the sea.

@chacham Nisan rightly corrects my answer to say that the re'em was too big to enter the teiva so it survived by putting its nostrils in the teiva. The following are sources

[Zevachim 113b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zevachim.113b.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) where the animal is called the “reima” “רימא" and

[Yalkut Shimoni](http://www.aspaklaria.info/040_MEM/%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%95%D7%9C.htm).

Answer (score 1):

They also say the Leviathan survived as it is a sea creature.

Comment: Suse welcome again to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. One of the important characteristic of MY is its reliance on sources, since we don't know you personally. Answers without sources are likely to be reclassified as comments, don't take it personally. Hope to see you around!